# ftp upload file corrupted in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

hello i have this code to upload image or word file through c# by using ftp.

the code works fine it uploads the file to ftp but file goes corrupted after uploading please advice what is wrong in this thanks

```
    //FTP Server URL.
    string ftp = "ftp://ftpip/";

    //FTP Folder name. Leave blank if you want to upload to root folder.
    string ftpFolder = "folder path to upload";

    byte[] fileBytes = null;

    //Read the FileName and convert it to Byte array.
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
    {
        fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());
        fileStream.Close();
    }

    try
    {
        //Create FTP Request.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp + ftpFolder + fileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        //Enter FTP Server credentials.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "ftppassowrd");
        request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
        request.EnableSsl = false;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        lblMessage.Text += fileName + " uploaded.<br />";
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception((ex.Response as FtpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
    }
```

Comment: StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8)  Even better : byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

Comment: can you adjust in my code i am newbie and completely lost

Comment: StreamReader is designed for text which images/words documents are not.  Use a BinaryReader or just use CopyTo to copy the InputStream to the RequestStream.

Comment: Made code change.

Comment: @jdweng Why do you edit OP's question? If you have an answer, post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `BinaryReader` instead of getting the bytes as UTF8 encoding. You should change it;

```
using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

to

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
{
    fileBytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);
}
```

Comment: can you please adjust your code in my code please so i get a complete code

Comment: Answer updated...

Comment: its giving error https://snag.gy/2MitXq.jpg

Comment: it works lots of Thanks Stormcloak.

Comment: the same code will work with word file and mp4? please advice

Comment: It will work any type of files.